# JavaScript Grid Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have created an Array of Objects:

```js
let myArray = [
    {myObject: "This is object number 1"},
    {myObject: "This is object number 2"},
    {myObject: "This is object number 3"},
    {myObject: "This is object number 4"},
    {myObject: "This is object number 5"},
];
```

I have created a function to paginate this Array:

```js
const paginator = (items, page, per_page) => {
  let offset = (page - 1) * per_page;
  let paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page);
  let total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page);

  return {
    page: page,
    per_page: per_page,
    pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : null,
    next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : null,
    total: items.length,
    total_pages: total_pages,
    data: paginatedItems
  };
};
```

I have then created an Arrow Function containing the HTML code to be displayed.

```js
const formatItem = item => `<div class="card" ${item.category}">
<div class="image-container"><img src="${item.image}" />
//Other div classes and text
</div>`;
```

I have then run the paginator function using the formatItem function as a parameter:

```js
productContainer.innerHTML = paginator(products, currentPage, perPage)
      .data.map(item => formatItem(item)).join("");
```

The objects were displayed on the page correctly. I then tried to make the objects display in rows, instead of columns. I tried to do this using the CSS `display: grid` and `display: flex` properties. However, neither property displayed the objects in rows, instead of columns.

I have created a grid layout in CSS using the following code:

```
#products {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    padding: 2em 50px;
}
```

How could I cause the objects to show in rows, instead of columns?

The link to more of my code is:
[codepen.io/programmer90000/pen/NWLYMax](https://codepen.io/programmer90000/pen/NWLYMax)

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  At a glance this looks very confusing: `products.innerHTML = paginator(products, currentPage, perPage)`  What *specifically* is `products`?  The left side of that statement implies that it's an HTML element, whereas the right side of that statement implies that it's an array.

Comment: products is an array of objects

Comment: Then what is `products.innerHTML = ...` meant to accomplish and why?

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: is `productContainer` the element with id `#products`??

Comment: ```productContainer``` is the element with id ```#products```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out finally what's happening in your code.

First there's a bug in your JS. You forgot to close a `<div>` in the function **formatItem**. This is the correct one:

```js
const formatItem = (item) => `
  <div class="card" ${item.category}">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="${item.image}" />
      <div class="container">
        <h6 class="brand-name">${item.manufacturer}</h6>
        <h5 class="product-name">${item.brandName.toUpperCase()}</h5>
        <h6 class="price">£${item.price}</h6>
        <button class="add-to-basket">Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;
```

This will fix the structure (HTML) of your document. Once the HTML fixed, you still need this style:

```css
#products {
  display: flex;
}
```

and you'll get your products on a row.

Answer (score -1):

The following ruleset will put each child of `#products` on a line (row).

```css
#products {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

So ensure that the variable `productContainer` is actually the element `#products` in order for the layout to work.

Comment: This has not worked?

Comment: This is strange. Can you share more of the coee that you have in order for us to understand the stucture of your website? Thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/programmer90000/pen/NWLYMax

Comment: Thanks for the codepen snippet! However I do not see any product there. There are only Category buttons

Comment: I have updated the page to include the objects. I forgot to update the image link before. Sorry

Comment: I'm writing a new answer. I solved your issue